# How can I convert a datatime into a time decimal

Tags: python, pandas

I have two columns, Picking End Time and Picking Start Time.

**First I converted them to datetime**

```py
data['Picking Start Time'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Picking Start Time'])
data['Picking End Time'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Picking End Time'])
```

**After that I wanted to see the picking time**

```py
data['Picking Time'] = data['Picking End Time'] - data['Picking Start Time']
```

**To strip the date and have just the time I used**

```py
data['Picking Time'] = data['Picking Time'].astype(str).map(lambda x: x[7:])
```

**Now, my next challenge is to transform the Picking Time into Decimal Time, but I cannot find anything that can help.**

Comment: Can you add some data sample and expected ouput?

Comment: https://ibb.co/Br3yXxc
I want to replicate that AVG Pace column. So basically I need to divide the amount of lines by the Picking Time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First remove:

```
data['Picking Time'] = data['Picking Time'].astype(str).map(lambda x: x[7:])
```

Use [`Series.dt.total_seconds`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.total_seconds.html) and if necessary divide by scalar `60` or `3600`:

```
#seconds
data['Picking Time'] = data['Picking Time'].dt.total_seconds()

#minutes
data['Picking Time'] = data['Picking Time'].dt.total_seconds() / 60

#hours
data['Picking Time'] = data['Picking Time'].dt.total_seconds() / 3600
```

Comment: I get this error:
AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values

Comment: @Dan-AlexandruJecu - Do you remove `data['Picking Time'] = data['Picking Time'].astype(str).map(lambda x: x[7:])` ?

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!
But I don't get the same values as in Sheets. In sheets, I was multiplying the time with 24.

Comment: So I discovered what I need. I need to multiply that time difference by 24.